# How do i call a method/function in a stateful widget from another stateful widget file flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

Hello guys i have been trying to call a method that is responsible for my bottom sheet modal in a Stateful Widget Class :

```
class _AllMerchantJobsListViewState extends State<AllMerchantJobsListView> {
     void merchantDetails(BuildContext ctx) {
    final controller = Get.find<HomeController>();
    final urlImages = [
      'assets/icon/instagram.png',
      'assets/icon/instagram.png',
      'assets/icon/instagram.png',
      'assets/icon/instagram.png',
      'assets/icon/instagram.png',
    ];
    void openGallery() => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => GalleryWidget(urlImages: urlImages),
        ));

    showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      elevation: 10,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: ctx,
      builder: (ctx) => FractionallySizedBox(
        heightFactor: 0.95,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(30.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(30.0)),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 11,
              ),
              Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                  width: 40,
                  child: DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xffEEEEEE),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Share',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: Color(0xff263B4F),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.shortcut_outlined,
                          size: 25,
                          color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    GetBuilder(
                        init: HomeController(),
                        builder: (context) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                controller.toggleLikedIcon();
                                controller.isLiked.isTrue
                                    ? addedToFavoriteToast()
                                    : null;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              child: controller.isLiked.isFalse
                                  ? Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                                      size: 22, color: Color(0xff34495E))
                                  : Icon(
                                      Icons.favorite_outlined,
                                      size: 22,
                                      color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                                    ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
    }
    }
   }
}
```

I am trying to call `merchantDetails` from the above Stateful Class to an `onTap` function of another file in my project that also is a stateful widget.

```
class _AllMerchantJobsGridViewState extends State<AllMerchantJobsGridView> {
        @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.find<HomeController>();

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},

},
},
}
```

How do i go about this?

I have tried to used VoidCallBack but for some reasons i have no idea why, it doesn't work.

For emphasis, i use GetX state management.

Comment: try removing underscore from _AllMerchantJobsListViewState and in _AllMerchantJobsGridViewState access it in this way: AllMerchantJobsListViewState. merchantDetails

Comment: @HitarthChhunchha it gives me an error 'instance member 'merchantDetails' can't be accessed using static access

Answer (score 0):

to avoid this problem create a class that has urlImages as member variable, in this way you will access to it easily.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).